# Example for S3 method roxygen documentation not working?

Tags: r, roxygen2, roxygen

When I use devtools::check() on my package, it produces an error suggesting my example doesn't work. When just running the function normally outside of the package it works just fine, so I'm wondering what the issue could be?

It produces error:

```
 Error in UseMethod("decision_lm") : 
    no applicable method for 'decision_lm' applied to an object of class "function"
  Calls: decision_lm
  Execution halted
```

This is my roxygen skeleton

```
#' Decision of linear regression test
#'
#' @description Gives the decision of retention or rejection for a linear
#' regression test
#'
#' @param fit1_lm list
#' @param ... other arguments
#'
#' @return characters
#'
#' @examples
#' fit1_lm <- fit_lm <- function(dat1) {
#' model <- lm(dat1$weight ~ dat1$height)
#' f1 <- summary(model)$coefficients[2,1]
#' f2 <- confint(model)[2,1]
#' f3 <- confint(model)[2,2]
#' f4 <- summary(model)$coefficients[2,3]
#' f5 <- df.residual(model)
#' f6 <- summary(model)$coefficients[2,4]
#' structure(
#'   list(beta_hat = f1, CI_Lower = f2, CI_Upper = f3, t.value = f4, df = f5, p.value = f6),
#'   class = "mytest") # Returns object of class mytest
#' }
#' fit1_lm(project2022)
#' decision_lm(fit1_lm)
#' @export
decision_lm <- function(fit1_lm, ...) {
  UseMethod("decision_lm")
}
#' @method decision_lm mytest
#' @export
decision_lm.mytest <- function(fit1_lm, ...) {
  if (fit1_lm[6] <= 0.05) {
    glue::glue("We reject the null hypothesis, as the p-value <= 0.05")
  } else if (fit1_lm[6] > 0.05) {
    glue::glue("We do not reject the null hypothesis, as the p-value > 0.05")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says `no applicable method for 'decision_lm' applied to an object of class "function"`, which tells you that the object you passed to `decision_lm` is a function, not an object for which you've defined a method.

In fact, your example has `decision_lm(fit1_lm)`, so it is trying to use the `fit1_lm` function as the argument, not the result of calling that function.

If you change your example to something like

```
#' fit <- fit1_lm(project2022)
#' decision_lm(fit)
```

it should work.

Comment: Thank you so much, I managed to resolve the issue!